# What is the best way to implement a reordering method?

Tags: c#, code-readability

I have some code that is supposed to assign some values to its properties according to a given order.

Here is some sample code that will do the job:

```
public class AnimalCount
{
    public int Dogs;
    public int Cats;
    public int Fish;
    public int Birds;

    public void RankValues(string first, string second, string third, string fourth)
    {
        string property = "";
        int value = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: property = first;  value = 10; break;
                case 1: property = second; value = 12; break;
                case 2: property = third;  value = 19; break;
                case 3: property = fourth; value = 20; break;
            }
            switch (property)
            {
                case "dogs":  Dogs  = value; break;
                case "cats":  Cats  = value; break;
                case "fish":  Fish  = value; break;
                case "birds": Birds = value; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some problems with this code, however.

1. The main problem is how to pass the parameters. With this method, since they are passed as strings, we lose type safety. We could thus have duplicates or mismatched strings. We could use enums, but then we still have the risk of duplicates, and we would have to do some code duplication to make it work.
2. The switches are ugly. It feels like code duplication somehow.

Is there any better solution than just filling the code with exception handling? Seems awfully ugly to me.

If you must know, I'm trying to write a function that takes a requested order of ability scores in Dungeons and Dragons and rolls for them in your selected order.

Comment: Are you using a specific language? Looks c#/java to me?

Comment: yeah it's C# but the question would apply for any procedural language really

Comment: c# is object oriented not procedural.

Comment: Yeah when I say "procedural" i mean it as a synonym of "imperative", not in the "strictly procedural" sense. All OO languages (that i know of) are also imperative languages.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted code that compiled. :-)

Comment: Why aren't you using array for individual values?

Comment: it compiles for me just fine (in powershell using `add-type`, which should also compile in VS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
public class AnimalCount
{
    public int Dogs;
    public int Cats;
    public int Fish;
    public int Birds;

    private Dictionary<string, Action<int>> rankers
        = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>()
    {
        { "dogs", v => Dogs = v },
        { "cats", v => Cats = v },
        { "fish", v => Fish = v },
        { "birds", v => Birds = v },
    };

    private Action<string, int> setRank = (t, v) =>
    {
        if (rankers.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            rankers[t](v);
        }
    };

    public RankValues(string first, string second, string third, string fourth)
    {
        setRank(first, 10);
        setRank(second, 12);
        setRank(third, 19);
        setRank(fourth, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: well i gave up on this project a while ago, but i think it's still a good question... given the time lapse, my brain tells me a Dict is definitely the way to go, but possibly a different way... posting my own answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if I'm following you, but can you not simply take in an ordered collection of 4 parameters?

```
public void doWhatever(String[] orderedParams) {
    this.animals = orderedParams;
    // ... 
    this.doTheThing(animals[0], 10);
    this.doTheThing(animals[1], 12);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would be a nice container for your results, as you are essentially wanting a key/value pair. If you feed two collections into your rank function

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Rank(string[] orderedKeys, int[] orderedValues)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> rankedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < orderedKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        rankedDictionary.Add(orderedKeys[i], orderedValues[i]);
    }
    return rankedDictionary;
}

public void CallRank()
{
    string[] orderedKeys = new[] { "dogs", "cats", "fish", "birds" };
    int[] orderedValues = new[] { 10, 12, 19, 20 };

    Dictionary<string,int> rankedResults =  Rank(orderedKeys, orderedValues);

    int catsValue = rankedResults["cats"];
}
```

The reason I asked if you were using C# is because if you are worried about strongly typed variables, instead of using strings of "cat" and "dog" etc. You can use an Enum in c#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

```
public enum Animals
{
    Dog
    Cat
    ....
}
```

so you dictionary would be of type

```
Dictionary<Animals, int>
```

and you would access it as so

```
int dogValue = rankedDictionary[Animals.Dog];
```

Comment: yes i was thinking of using a Dictionary and enums... but I really want the public properties there to be named as they are. of course i can always use their getter to make that work, but that seems like too much effort for something so simple... also the enums seem silly as well because i want the properties there... i think im gonna stick with what i had originally

Answer (score 0):

Taking ideas from the other answers, I believe the best way to implement this would be the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class AnimalCount
{
    public int Dogs { get { return animals["dogs"]; } }
    public int Cats { get { return animals["cats"]; } }
    public int Fish { get { return animals["fish"]; } }
    public int Birds { get { return animals["birds"]; } }

    private Dictionary<string, int> animals = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void RankValues(string first, string second, string third, string fourth)
    {
        animals[first] = 10;
        animals[second] = 12;
        animals[third] = 19;
        animals[fourth] = 20;
    }
}
```

and with an enum for type safety:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum Animals
{
    Dogs, Cats, Fish, Birds
}

public class AnimalCount
{
    public int Dogs { get { return animals[Animals.Dogs]; } }
    public int Cats { get { return animals[Animals.Cats]; } }
    public int Fish { get { return animals[Animals.Fish]; } }
    public int Birds { get { return animals[Animals.Birds]; } }

    private Dictionary<Animals, int> animals = new Dictionary<Animals, int>();

    public void RankValues(Animals first, Animals second, Animals third, Animals fourth)
    {
        animals[first] = 10;
        animals[second] = 12;
        animals[third] = 19;
        animals[fourth] = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: with only four possible values, maybe an enum isn't worth it. also granted, with a larger number of possible values, or for an arbitrary number of possible values, passing in some kind of orderedParams would be better, as per Ben Griffiths' answer